# How can I include assets of a dash app into an exe file created with pyinstaller --onefile?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, plotly-dash

I am trying to package a dash app into a single pyinstaller .exe and am running into some trouble including the assets folder.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
# get temp working directory
    import sys
    import os
    def resource_path(relative_path):

# get absolute path to resource
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

print(resource_path("assets"))
```

This gives me a the path to the current working directory/assets. It works in anaconda environment as well as in the .exe, giving me the right path in the console.

But the next part is where I run into trouble:

```
# create app
app = dash.Dash(__name__, assets_url_path=resource_path("assets"))
```

Normally, `assets_url_path=` can be used to set the asset path for dash apps. Specifically, I have my css file for formatting stored here, but it should be the same process for any asset. For some reason, however, the assets don't get used in the pyinstaller version of the app, despite `print(resource_path("assets"))` showing the correct path in the system's `Temp` directory. I can even navigate there and see my `styles.css`, but somehow dash doesn't pick it up.

What confuses me is that the exact same code works perfectly fine in my anaconda environment. The only difference should be that the temporary path is my home directory instead. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and after experimenting with stuff I have finally found the solution if you still need it!!!

It is very simple... all you have to do is type:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__, assets_folder=resource_path('assets'))
```

so the only difference is to type 'assets_folder' instead of 'assets_url_path' and it seems to work for --onefile!

Comment: Thanks! I have since gone fully online with my app, but I'm sure it will come up again at some point.

Comment: The documentation doesn't describe it in the same detail I wanted.  Your answer helped, and looking at the source helped. https://github.com/plotly/dash/blob/dev/dash/dash.py#L111

Comment: also adding --add-data 'assets:assets' helped me

Comment: resource_path is unknown in my code. What is this?